# 4 faces sharing an edge. Which pairs of faces belong together.

Tags: geometry

I'm sorry for the somewhat vague title, but I'm not sure how to better describe the problem.

I have a single solid in 3D (arbitrary, closed collection of faces). This solid internally has a part where 1 component touches another along a single edge. You can see this in the picture below. [image: Touch components]

The data here is represented by a single edge, that belongs to 4 different faces.

For our algorithm we need to know which pairs of faces belong together. By this I mean the pairs of faces that form the boundary of the solid together for that part of the solid. In the picture below that means bottom with right and top with left.

[image: 2D representation of touching components]

The concept of how to determine this doesn't seem too difficult. I would take one of the faces, rotate it around the common edge in the opposite direction of it's normal. The first face I meet in the process is the face you want. But I'm not sure how to express this in a calculation.